# convert between float[4] and qbytearray

Tags: c++, qt, udp, qbytearray

the current assignment requires me to convert between qbytearray and float[4]
however the online methods using memcpy(), (reinterpret_cast(&f), sizeof(f)), don't work
transforming a float array to qbytearray and then reversely just get  0x66fc70 (originally array   float  fVar[4] = { 1.1, 2.3, 9.5, 0.2 })

the only work one using tofloat, however this is for 1 float, not for array
please don't directly copy from other forum unless test and show it returns original float array after double side conversion

Comment: `auto qba = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&fVar), sizeof fVar);`

Comment: how to do it reversely?

Answer (score 0):

you can read them doing:

```
qint32 BYTES_TO_READ{4 * 4};
float myFloatArray[4];
mySocket->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(myFloatArray), BYTES_TO_READ);
```

Comment: this convert the float to Qbytearray (is it), but how can I do it reversely